# CSS-opacity/transparency of an image

Tags: css

how to remove the transparency/opacity of the `<img>` element when the user hovers over it with the mouse pointer?

Comment: please share your html/css. To help you precisely.  Also try this style 
  img:hover {opacity: 1;}

Comment: and add some snippet or jsfiddle

Comment: .element:hover {opacity:0;}

Answer (score 2):

Opacity value is 1 by default, so you have to change it to less than 1 then on hover selector you make again 1.

something you have to be aware of that all child elements will be effected by the parent div opacity.

to make cooler you can use `transition: all 0.5s ease;` for example with it

> Read more about it [here ( Css transition)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/)
>   
>   More about [css opacity here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/opacity/)

```css
div {
height: 40px;
width: 100px;
background: #007cb0;
padding: 10px 20px;
color: white;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;

opacity: .4;
}

div:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set  `opacity: 1;` on hover (`:hover`) element
`opacity: 1` is **default** definition that mean without any `opacity` 
Learn about `:hover`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

```css
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
img:hover {
    opacity: 1;/* To remove opacity */
}
```

```html
<img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg" alt="Forest" width="170" height="100">
```

Comment: tell me for more help